# working with old version of delphi project

Tags: delphi

I am trying to open an old project, with delphi 7 and 2010 but an error occurs which says 
class TSCButton not found. ignore the error and continue?NOTE: ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values to be lost.
when i click cancel another error occurs i.e error creating form:Class TSCButton not found.
does this problem has to do with installing relevant packages or importing Activex for it to function.
Any ideas of how to go about with this errors?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your form is using a control called `TSCButton`, and you don't have it installed in your current copy of Delphi.

There are really only two choices:

1. Install whatever component package contains `TSCButton` into your current project.
2. Ignore the error, allow the form designer to remove it, and then replace it (and fix any code that refers to `TSCButton`) with a different button. (How difficult this is depends on what extra functionality `TSCButton` has over a standard `TButton`.)

<strike>A quick Google search doesn't turn up any obvious hits for `TSCButton Delphi`, so I can't really tell you where to try and find it. Perhaps someone else will come along that's familiar with it and can point you in the right direction.</strike>

It seems `TScButton` is part of the [`SkinEngine`](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56362) component library, which allowed you to provide some visual styles to your Delphi forms and controls. I don't know if it's still available or not, though. The link to `ksdev.com` from that article simply shows an empty page with a header for KSDev at the top.

Comment: The man behind KSDEV is Eugene Kryukov. He made a component set called VGScene. All was sold to Embarcadero were he became an employee. The components set became `FireMonkey`.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks. I knew about Eugene, VGScene, and FM. Didn't know about the connection to SkinEngine. :-)

Comment: thanks Ken for the useful information.Besides do you have any idea of the skin used since there are a varieties such as alpha controls, vclskins, suiskins..

Comment: The skins used are actually from a product called `SkinEngine`. :-)